# Model Constructor In Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Good Day, I've tried using a constructor for my model and it flashes an error...

> ```
> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\DV::__construct(), 0 passed in
> ```
>
> E:\Apps\SRAWeb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents.php
>   on line 35 & exactly 2 expected.

This is my code:

```
protected $date;

public function __construct($attributes = array(), Request $request){
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->date = Carbon::parse($request->toDate)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

I've tested it and come up with is that if I try to inject **Request** Class to my constructor. The errors flash.. but if I remove the Request class it runs smoothly. Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you can't inject a `Request` class neither in your `Model` constructors nor in your `Controller` constructor, because they don't have to do anything with `Http` calls and they are not being `"hit"` by any kind of `Request` so injecting them into constructors won't work. You can only inject `Request` in any valid method that actually receives an `Http` hit, to better put it, you can use `Request` in all methods/actions you have defined are being used inside of your `routes`. With an exception of some other layers in `Laravel` which provide the access to `Request` like [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware) but they are not inside of a `constructor` as you can see, but rather in a separate method.